# How to change parent element background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap accordion, I need to change (.panel) background when its child .collapse has .in

[**Demo**](https://fiddle.jshell.net/alpeshlahad/qjfsnpyc/6/)

Seeking below result :
[image]

Comment: Be specific:`.panel-body`, `.panel-heading`....?

Comment: check my updated answer which may help!

Comment: how about the new answer

Answer (score 1):

Try something as simple as below.

```js
$('.panel-title a').click(function() {
  $('.panel').removeClass('bg');
  $('.panel-heading').removeClass('bg');
  $(this).closest('.panel').addClass('bg');
  $(this).closest('.panel-heading').addClass('bg');
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading {
  background: none;
}

.bg {
  background-color: cyan !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default bg">
    <div class="panel-heading bg">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
                Collapsible Group 1</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">
                Collapsible Group 2</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">
                Collapsible Group 3</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it wont work if you click the same element again . the color will remains there

Comment: Yes, this is that :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.panel-title').click(function(){
    $(this).css('color', 'red');  // Here you can change color of its any parent element by using DOM traversing functions
  });
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/qjfsnpyc/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Accordion Events to detect, when accordion is open. then change it's backgroud color accordingly.

```
$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){
    $('.panel').css("background-color", "#f5f5f5");
});
```

**[Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/qjfsnpyc/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

How about this one.

https://fiddle.jshell.net/rtzz25ta/

made some changes in the click event

```js
$(function(){
 $('.panel-title').click(function(){
   $(".panel-heading").css('background','white');    
   $(this).parent().css('background', 'gray'); 
 
      if ( !$(this).find("a").hasClass( "collapsed" ) ) 
      { 
        $(this).parent().css('background', 'white');   
      }
  
   
  });
});
```

```css
body {padding: 50px;}

.panel-body
{
  background-color:gray;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:gray">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
        Collapsible Group 1</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in" >
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
      minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
      commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">
        Collapsible Group 2</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
      minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
      commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">
        Collapsible Group 3</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
      minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
      commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution  https://fiddle.jshell.net/qjfsnpyc/8/

```js
$('.panel').click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('active')){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  } else {
    $(this)
      .addClass('active')
      .siblings('div.panel')
      .removeClass('active');
  }
});

$('#collapse1').closest('div.panel').addClass('active');
```

```css
body {padding: 50px;}
.panel-default>.panel-heading {background: none !important;}

.active {
  background: #eee !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
        Collapsible Group 1</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
      minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
      commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">
        Collapsible Group 2</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
      minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
      commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">
        Collapsible Group 3</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
      minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
      commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.